# Printing the process ID and parent ID of all programs currently in the Ram using C programming language

Tags: c

In C programming language, I know how to get the process ID and the parent process ID of the current program using getpid() and getppid() respectively. But is there a way I can write a program that prints all the process ID and parent process ID of all the programs currently running in the RAM in C programming language?

Comment: This is what the `ps` program does, and you could read its source.  But the mechanisms are system-dependent; there is nothing in standard C or POSIX to accomplish this.  So you'll have to say what OS you are using.

Comment: I guess [proc file system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html) if you are in Linux

Comment: In Linux, for instance, you iterate over the `/proc` directory and parse the file `/proc/NN/stat`  or `/proc/NN/status` for each process.

Comment: For linux you might get some hints [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132224/is-it-possible-to-get-process-group-id-from-proc).

Comment: In Windows, you can use ToolHelp API. Look at [process walking documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/process-walking).

Comment: Which OS are you talking about?